# Error while receiving date as parameter input

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, runtime-error, procedure

I am getting an error when I plug in a date to test a parameter I am working on.  The error is:

```
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

Here is my test script:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  type tempcursor is ref cursor;
  v_cur_result tempcursor;
  errcode number;
  errmesg varchar2(1000);
  p_statusmnemonic_in         acts.ct_cu_act_medrecon_pg.varchararrayplstype;
  p_processtypemnemonic_in    transactionprocesslog.processtypemnemonic%type; 
  p_primarymemberplanid_in    membermedicalreconcilationhdr.primarymemberplanid%type;
  p_assigneduserid_in         membermedicalreconcilationhdr.assigneduserid%type;
  p_accountorgid_in           membermedicalreconcilationhdr.accountorgid%type;
  p_reconstatusmnemonic_in    membermedicalreconcilationhdr.reconciliationstatusmnemonic%type;
  p_estimatedenddt_in         membermedicalreconcilationhdr.estimatedenddt%type;
  p_actualenddt_in            membermedicalreconcilationhdr.actualenddt%type;
  p_inserteddate_in           membermedicalreconcilationhdr.inserteddt%type;
  p_insertedby_in             membermedicalreconcilationhdr.insertedby%type;
  p_updateddate_in           membermedicalreconcilationhdr.updateddt%type;
  p_updatedby_in           membermedicalreconcilationhdr.updatedby%type;

begin
  p_statusmnemonic_in(1) := ('OPEN');
  p_statusmnemonic_in(2) := ('SUSPENDED_PRIOR_TO_COMPARE');
  ct_cu_act_medrecon_pg.sps_get_patientmedrecs_hdr      
  (p_statusmnemonic_in,'NO','26-JAN-14',v_cur_result, errcode, errmesg);

   loop
fetch v_cur_result into     p_primarymemberplanid_in,p_assigneduserid_in,p_accountorgid_in,p_reconstatusmnemonic_in,
                        p_estimatedenddt_in,p_actualenddt_in,p_inserteddate_in,p_insertedby_in,
                        p_updateddate_in,p_updatedby_in,p_processtypemnemonic_in;

  dbms_output.put_line(' planid '||p_primarymemberplanid_in||' userid '||p_assigneduserid_in);

  exit when v_cur_result%notfound;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(' error code '||errcode||' message '||errmesg);
end;
```

I dont get an error when the date is set to '24-JAN-13' but the second I change anything I get that error.  Here are the two estimated date fields in the table I am looking at:

```
24-JAN-13 04.29.19.989847000 PM
28-JAN-13 08.52.27.187015000 PM
```

Here is my proc:

```
  procedure sps_get_patientmedrecs_hdr (
    p_statusmnemonic_in       in varchararrayplstype,
    p_processtypemnemonic_in  in transactionprocesslog.processtypemnemonic%type,
    p_estimatedenddt_in       in membermedicalreconcilationhdr.estimatedenddt%type,
    p_return_cur_out          out sys_refcursor,
    p_err_code_out            out number,
    p_err_mesg_out            out varchar2)
  is
     lv_varchararray         varchararray := varchararray();
  begin
    if p_statusmnemonic_in.count > 0
    then
      for rec1 in 1..p_statusmnemonic_in.count
      loop
        lv_varchararray.extend(1);
        lv_varchararray(rec1) := p_statusmnemonic_in(rec1);
      end loop;

        open p_return_cur_out for
        select h.membermedreconciliationhdrskey,
               h.primarymemberplanid,
               h.assigneduserid,
               h.accountorgid,
               h.reconciliationstatusmnemonic,
               h.estimatedenddt,
               h.actualenddt,
               h.inserteddt,
               h.insertedby,
               h.updateddt,
           h.updatedby
        from membermedicalreconcilationhdr h
        where h.reconciliationstatusmnemonic in (select *
                                             from table (cast(lv_varchararray as varchararray)))
        and h.estimatedenddt <= nvl(p_estimatedenddt_in, h.estimatedenddt)
        and not exists (select *
                        from transactionprocesslog tpl
                        where tpl.transactiontypemnemonic = 'MEDREC'
                        and tpl.transactionid = h.primarymemberplanid
                        and nvl(p_processtypemnemonic_in, tpl.processtypemnemonic) = tpl.processtypemnemonic);
    else
        open p_return_cur_out for
        select h.membermedreconciliationhdrskey,
               h.primarymemberplanid,
               h.assigneduserid,
               h.accountorgid,
               h.reconciliationstatusmnemonic,
               h.estimatedenddt,
               h.actualenddt,
               h.inserteddt,
               h.insertedby,
               h.updateddt,
               h.updatedby
        from membermedicalreconcilationhdr h; 
    end if;

  p_err_code_out := 0;  
  exception
    when others then
      p_err_code_out := -1;
      p_err_mesg_out := 'error in ct_cu_act_medrecon_pg.sps_get_patientmedrecs_hdr => ' || sqlerrm;
  end sps_get_patientmedrecs_hdr;
```

I've tried the to_date function but received the same error.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're treating a string like it's a date, which may or may not work depending on your NLS settings. Whenever Oracle sees a string where it expects a date it tries to do an implicit date conversion based whether that string happens to match your particular session's date formatting parameter. This is a very common source of errors.

To use a proper date you can use the to_date function like so:

```
to_date('26-JAN-14','DD-MON-RR')
```

or use the native syntax for specifying date literals, which is what I would recommend:

```
date'2014-1-26'
```

Comment: I tried those and they didnt work already.  Im starting to think it might be something other than the date, but I cant find what else it could be.

Comment: what does sps_get_patientmedrecs_hdr expect to receive? a date, number or varchar?

Comment: Its supposed to get the fields from the table depending on the requirements, which are then passed to the cursor.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to ask is if you could confirm that the db column for estimatedenddt column in the membermedicalreconcilationhdr table is indeed a date. I've run into similar problems where all my params were right but the db field I was comparing against was unexpectedly a varchar2 instead of a proper date and one of the rows had incorrectly formatted date string.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah its a date 
`ESTIMATEDENDDT TIMESTAMP(6)`

Comment: That's what Iwas just thinking. The order of the columns in your test script doesn't match the order of the columns in the "open p_return_cur_out for" clause in the actual method.

Comment: Im such a doofus, thats what the problem was.  Sometimes youre looking so hard for this certain thing to be wrong, you miss the hand that just smacked you in the face.  Thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: No prob! Deciphering Oracle's supremely unhelpful error messages always makes for a good puzzle since they're so charmingly efficient at making you look at the wrong place.